# preview file from file input field php

Tags: php

Is it possible to preview the file that is selected in the input field before taking any actions?

ex.
I will upload a text file so I will select it then before I click the upload button I want to preview the text file in tables or something like that.

Comment: Not with PHP. Maybe with javascript, but I doubt it. Most likely you will not be able to preview it until it has been uploaded.

Comment: I see, I am thinking of storing it first into a temp var before storing it into the database, but im kinda mess up with the codes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RichardTheobald mentioned, it isn't possible with PHP to preview a file before it's uploaded, however, with JavaScript it is.

To read a text file before it's uploaded with JavaScript, you'll need to use a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object. You'll be able to get the list of files from the `<input type="file">` element and pop each of these into a `FileReader`. [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files) has a good article on reading local files which I've adapted to this question in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/epao79yk/).

```
input.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];

    // Only render plain text files
    if (!file.type === "text/plain")
        return;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Once the FileReader loads, pop the result into an output element
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerText = event.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

Comment: I also consider that JS but it just read the plane text file right? but I want to preview the file in tables so it can be read easily. anyways thank you for this I will use this one.

Comment: @VinceOsana Absolutely. Glad to help!